# Symplectic geometry as a prerequisite for Heegaard Floer homology

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, symplectic-geometry

I would like to study Heegaard Floer homology in the future in the connection to knot theory.

I read a wikipedia article and it seems that I need to first learn a symplectic geometry (topology?). I took a basic differential geometry class. But I have never studied symplectic geometry.

What is a good way to study symplectic geometry in the scope of studying Heegaard Floer homology in the future? What textbook is adequate fo this purpose.

Also, what are the other prerequisites?

I know basics of algebraic topology.

Comment: I was briefly considering studying this, and I was told that McDuff--Salamon's "Intro to Symplectic Manifolds" is standard and that Ana Cannas da Silva's book is harder and contains lots of important stuff.

Comment: Do you have someone in your department who can give you some guidance? there is a lot of symplectic geometry in both of these books that is not relevant to you and there are a number of technical points about holomorphic curves that are not explained in these books. A correct answer to your question, imo, requires more information about what you know and about what you are interested in doing. Unfortunately, even with this information, I wouldn't be qualified to give you a good answer, since I don't work in Heegaard Floer homology.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend [this book](http://www.math.ist.utl.pt/~acannas/Books/lsg.pdf) by Ana Cannas da Silva to learn about symplectic geometry.

However, if your primary interest is Heegaard Floer Knot homology, you can dive right in, using the [combinatorial description](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610559) of Ciprian Manolescu, Peter Ozsváth, Zoltán Szabó, and Dylan Thurston and begin calculating.  Then, later approach it from the geometry of holomorphic disks.